# Retrieving data from MySQL database when click on an image

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a picture of a burger. When a user click on it I want to retrieve all the burgers from the database at the user's current city. I'm able to get user's city and assigned it to a variable. Now how do I use a GET method on a link without using a form? like...

```
<a href="demo.php?food=burger&city=currentcity"><img...></a>
```

I want to replace the 'currentcity' in the URL with a variable. The currentcity variable is actually a parameter in a function that is part of the geolocation and geocoder function that I used to locate the user's city...

```
function getCurrentCity(city){
   //city contains user's current city
}
```

I'm able to do this in a search form with GET method and assigning the 'city' variable to the search id like..

```
document.getElementById('searchId').value = city;
```

But how do I do it without a form? And with just a link? Should I use console.write (//and put all my links and HTML in here? And then concatenate the URL with current city variable?).. Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the Click event using jquery and inside event Call the URL which contains your server side code and db query to get the data by passing the parameters, then Display it as per requirement.

```
$('#BurgerBtn').on('click',function (e){       
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url :"/URL",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
    console.log('success',data);
},
error:function(exception){
 alert('Exeption:'+exception);
}
}); 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Do you know where I can read more about this? I want to know exactly what's going on with your provided code. Thank you

Comment: Just Type `Ajax Call using jquery` in google..You will get lot of interesting links..